# Sql server deadlock issue - query to find out long running trans doesnt return anything

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a query to find out long running transactions to resolve deadlock issue-

```
SELECT spid, cmd, status, loginame, open_tran, datediff(s, last_batch, getdate ()) AS [WaitTime(s)] 
FROM master..sysprocesses p 
WHERE open_tran > 0 
AND spid > 50 
AND datediff (s, last_batch, getdate ()) > 30 
ANd EXISTS (SELECT * FROM master..syslockinfo l 
WHERE req_spid = p.spid AND rsc_type <> 2)
```

But it doesn't return any rcord and i am still getting deadlock issue for my application. what could be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

- `DBCC TRACEON(1222,-1)` - to enable to trace flag, deadlock info will get logged to the log file
- `DBCC TRACESTATUS (1222, -1)` - to check status of trace flag
- `DBCC TRACEOFF (1222,-1)` - to disable trace flag

Answer (score 1):

I realize in some ways this is asking for clarification, but it's important enough that it belongs in an answer.

A Deadlock is a very specific occurrence where 2 processes are waiting for the same resource and they're in a catch-22 situation where they can't resolve it by waiting. Good reading [There is a very simple explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213032%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) even though it says SQL Server 2000. Also have a look at [this great script to reproduce it](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49692). Probably the most important thing to understand about deadlocks is that they're typically very fast. You get into a deadlock situation and SQL Server is smart enough to recognize it and kill one of the processes.

So if you still think you're having deadlocks, listen to answer #1 as the poster is correct. If you think you're having what people more loosely use the term "deadlock" for, which is locking and blocking where a process ties up a resource and all other processes need to wait. You troubleshoot those by running SQL Server Profiler and slowly honing in on the problem process(es).

Hopefully this will help clarify for future readers, if not the original poster. Make sure you know what you're actually researching!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with 
DBCC TRACEON (1204)